# Can wixproj file reference an environment variable?

Tags: msbuild, wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

Using wix 3.10.2.

I would like to reference an environment variable within a .wixproj file.

I have tried (exerpt from my .wixproj):

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <JavaDocsBaseDir>$(env.JAVADOCS)</JavaDocsBaseDir>
```

but I am getting the error:

```
error MSB4184: The expression """.JAVADOCS" cannot be evaluated. Method 'System.String.JAVADOCS' not found.
```

Tried removing the "env." with no luck.  Also tried using the windows env var format %JAVADOCS%, also with no luck.  What am I doing wrong?

I am calling the build via

```
msbuild ClientSetup.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

So, I have the ability to pass the data via commandline as well, if that is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `$(env.JAVADOCS)` or `%JAVADOCS%` is for use in the wix source (.wxs/.wxi) files. For the project you should use normal MSBuild syntax, not Wix syntax. Try `$(JAVADOCS)`

Comment: This ended up working.  I was sure I had tried it but it failed to work.  Set the env var from a batch file and kicked off the build, but I was getting that error.  Tried it again after some more fiddling and it worked.  Maybe I hadn't saved something earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You should use $(JAVADOCS).

Take a look at Microsoft documentation: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459.aspx

Comment: Appreciate the doc-link!